# rails ajax generated javascript link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This should be a simple one:

Given this link:

```
<a id="description_link_146" class="document_icon pull-left" data-slug="link-to-the-blog" data-remote="true" href="/challenges/link-to-the-blog/description_line"></a>
```

When clicked, it unobtrusively executes this js.erb view, modifying our link to trigger the javascript hideDescription() function:

```
$("#task_<%=@challenge.id%>").append("<%=j render partial: 'description_line', locals: {challenge: @challenge}%>");
$("#description_link_<%=@challenge.id%>").attr("href","javascript: hideDescription(<%=@challenge.id%>)");
```

This is the hideDescription function:

```
function hideDescription(id) {
    alert("hide");    
}
```

This link doesn't work. Any idea why? I know that in Jquery, I need to re-bind it after loading but this is pure javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is your code of js.erb file:

```
$("#task_<%=@challenge.id%>").append("<%=j render partial: 'description_line', locals: {challenge: @challenge}%>");
$("#description_link_<%=@challenge.id%>").attr("href","javascript: hideDescription(<%=@challenge.id%>)");
```

if your want just to hide link after click you can do like this:

```
$("#description_link_<%=@challenge.id%>").hide();
```

Comment: Yes, this could be a way to do but I have other things to add in the hideDescription function (like redefining the link).

Comment: you can all this stuff do in js.erb file or I don't understand what exactly you want to do

Comment: I use the js.erb to load a div. To close this div, I want to avoid the round trip to the server, so I prefer to have a javascript on the page. This javascript should just remove the description and reset the link to its original state. If you have a better way to do it, I'm wide open but I think that what I'm doing is very straight forward and the error should be quite tiny. Thanks for your helf

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that the problem was due to the fact the I used a remote link. I couldn't use javascript in the href with remote = true

Even changing the remote property to false didn't help. I guess that the link needed to be unbound but I don't know how to do that.

I ended up by creating a separate hide link and playing with hide() and show() methods:

Links:

```
<%= link_to "", description_line_challenge_path(challenge), class: "document_icon pull-left", id: "description_link_#{challenge.id}", data: {slug: challenge.slug}, remote: true %>
<%= link_to "", "javascript:hideDescription(#{challenge.id})", class: "document_icon pull-left", style: "display: none", id: "description_hide_link_#{challenge.id}", data: {slug: challenge.slug} %>
```

js.erb show file:

```
$("#task_<%=@challenge.id%>").append("<%=j render partial: 'description_line', locals: {challenge: @challenge}%>");
$("#description_link_<%=@challenge.id%>").hide();
$("#description_hide_link_<%=@challenge.id%>").show();
```

javascript function:

```
function hideDescription(id) {
    $("#task_description_" + id).remove();
    $("#description_link_" + id).show();
    $("#description_hide_link_" + id).hide();
}
```

This is not very much "the rails way" but I don't know of a better way.

Anyone does?